# rate control in java

Tags: java, performance, rate

I am looking for a good solution or probably an API to solve the following problem:

- My application does a task in a loop, for example it sends e-mails etc. I need to limit the average rate of messages to for example 100 messages per second or 1000 messages per last minute ...

No I am looking for an algorithm or an API which does exactly this task.

Comment: Is this to avoid raising alarms in SpamBots?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) to schedule tasks for a given period of time.

For example, to schedule 100 tasks per second you can say:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(nThreads);
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(mailSender, 0, 10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Obviously, you need to track how many tasks have executed and turn off the scheduler after the job is done.

Comment: Or have the scheduled task not do anything when there is nothing left to do. This avoids having to cancel and add it repeatedly.

Answer (score 4):

[Token bucket algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket) is very easy to implement and use yet very powerful. You can control the throughput at runtime and queue some requests to handle peeks.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way I can think of is to delay when to send each emails depending on how many are waiting.

```
final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor service = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
int ratePerSecond = ...

public static void execute(Runnable run) {
   int delay = 1000 * service.getQueue().size() / ratePerSecond;
   service.schedule(run, delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

This will ensure that the tasks are performed only as close to together as the rate allows.

Comment: I think its important to be simple enough that you can easily understand how its going to work. There are more sophisticated solutions but you probably don't need them.

Comment: Nice - simple and elegant!

Answer (score 3):

Guava has a [RateLimiter](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html) class that does exactly that.

Comment: Fixed dead link